# Prevent DIRECTORY access through parent URL

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, indexing, directory

I have a index listing of files from a folder on a website that is contained within an iframe of a webpage, however the index list can be access without even going through the webpage. Say for example "localhost/index.html" has the index list within an iframe for the folder "/root" but I can simply type "localhost/root" into the url bar and access the index of files without going through the webpage. Is there any possible way to edit the .htaccess file or otherwise to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Here are a couple awesome tutorials.

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Htaccess_tricks#Index_options
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome stuff! Very helpful, however I haven't found the answer for what I asked (well not yet at least). ill let you know if i have.